# Protect Password From Decompilation

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, password-protection

I have program that connect to a SqlServer by predetermined username & password.
Ex:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string UserName, Password;
    UserName = "Name";
    Password = "Pass";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
}
```

How can I protect the password from decompilation?

Comment: You can't. The best you can do is obfuscate it, but with a language like C# where you can disassemble the executable/library to pretty much the exact code it was compiled from, this isn't going to do much good.

Comment: @WillVousden Any language can be disassembled from the byte code. The result not as cleaning as disassembling IL is, but it is still readable. That is what encryption is for.

Comment: @Danny: So where do you store the encryption key?

Comment: @WillVousden You can build the decryption key at run time from bytes laying around your installation.

Comment: @DannyVarod: Right, but it has to be stored or generated according to some rules in the source code, which is readily available to anyone with a copy of ILDASM.

Comment: @WillVousden The only way to really secure the password is to use one time passwords e.g. a session ID from a remote login which can be confirmed remotely. The question is can the application work offline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply do not do that in the first place. The security system is designed to protect *users* from *attackers* who are trying to get the users to run bad code. It is not designed to protect *your program* from *its users*, which is what you are trying to do.

Hard-coding a user name and password into an executable is a worst practice, for multiple reasons. First, because it grants access to the database to people who *have your program*, not to *people who are authorized*. Second, it means that if you ever need to change the user name or password, then you need to re-ship the program. Third, if the password does get out, and it only needs to get out *once*, what happens? You have no way to restrict access to just the attacker.

A far better solution is to require that every user have their own account; make them type in the password. Or integrate the database access with some other identity-and-authorization scheme, like Windows authentication or whatever.

Comment: That still leaves the database open for registered users to view and use in any way. A better solution would be to not give direct access to the database - store it remotely and enable access only via a specific API.

Comment: @DannyVarod, that's why database servers have the ability to set permissions. These can be set to only allow users in group X to run set of stored procedures Y, etc,.. Sometimes a specific API (perhaps implemented as a SOAP service) is warranted, but sometimes it's overkill =)

Answer (score 3):

If this program will always be run on the same computer, you could put this information the connectionStrings section of your configuration file [and use DPAPI to encrypt it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Having your password encrypted is one thing. Having a dedicated user on your database, with just the set of necessary rights on database objects is another, much more important if you ask me.